# On Demand Resources crash - NSBundle Resource Request could not connect to its helper daemon

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, on-demand-resources

Getting a crash for using ODR(on demand resources) on iOS app with this description -

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSBundleResourceRequest
>   could not connect to its helper daemon

iOS Version common among crashes - 10.3.2

I'm seeing crashes in Crashlytics and am unable to reproduce this in debug mode without calling private methods. I have images and sound files included in my ODRs. Attaching the stack trace screen shot as well -  [ScreenShotofStackTrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99fxN.png)

I am also calling `-[NSBundleResourceRequest conditionallyBeginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler:]` from within a `dispatch_after` block. Could this be the culprit?

Any leads would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you consistently getting the crash, or is it inconsistent? Is it possible that endAccessingResources() is getting called before conditionallyBeginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler has completed?

Comment: This was probably the culprit. I removed it from the dispatch block and the crash was gone.

Answer (score -2):

In my case, closing Xcode, deleting files in the DerivedData folder, restarting Xcode, cleaning the project, and deleting the program from the simulator/device solved this problem.

Comment: Nope was happening on a live build :/